# How can I use a parameter that I get with scanf in another function?

Tags: c, function, user-defined-functions

```
#include <-stdio.h>
float q, w, e, v1, v2;
int h, j;

int eqn(float q, float w, float e);
float val(int x);

int main (){

    eqn(q,w,e);
    scanf("%d%d",&h,&j);

return 0;
}

int eqn(float q, float w, float e) {
    scanf("%f %f %f", &q, &w, &e);
    printf("Entered equation: %.2fx^2 + %.2fx + %.2f\n", q, w, e);
    v1=val(h);
    v2=val(j);
    printf("values %f %f", value1, value2);
}

float val(int x){
    float value = q*x*x+w*x+e;
    return value;
}
```

So, I want to get h and j values from the user and use them in eqn function in order to get the values. I am also requesting the q, w, e values from the user. 
How can I get both the coefficients of the equation and the points that I'd like to calculate the value on?

Comment: `eqn` uses `h` and `j` before they've been `scanf`-ed, so they still have value `0`.

Comment: Just as a note: The parameters `q`, `w`, `e` of `eqn()` shadow away the globally defined variables `q`, `w` and `e`.

Comment: yeah, but is there a way to make the variables global so their values are valid for all other functions?

Comment: can't you just switch the `scan("d"d",&h, &h);` before you call eqn?  Because all you variables are global (which the should not be), the value of `h, j` will be visible inside `eqn`?  Also, what is the hyphen in the include statement?

Comment: I can actually do that, but the question is that is there a way to use that for nested built-in function?

Answer (score 0):

Refrain from using global variables, as sooner or later your code gets much to messy, when doing so.

Just put the all in correct order and pass what is necessary:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int eqn(int h, int j);
float val(float q, float w, float e, int x);

int main(void)
{
  int h, j;

  scanf("%d%d", &h, &j);
  eqn(h, j);

  return 0;
}

int eqn(int h, int j) 
{
  float v1, v2;
  float q, w, e;

  scanf("%f %f %f", &q, &w, &e);

  printf("Entered equation: %.2fx^2 + %.2fx + %.2f\n", q, w, e);

  v1 = val(q, w, e, h);
  v2 = val(q, w, e, j);

  printf("values %f %f\n", v1, v2);
} 

float val(float q, float w, float e, int x)
{
  float value = q*x*x + w*x + e;
  return value;
}
```

If you want to call `val()` from main, switch to passing addresses to allow the caller to see what the callee assigned:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int eqn(float * pq, float * pw, float * pe);
float val(float q, float w, float e, int x);

int main(void)
{
  float q, w, e;
  int h, j;
  float v1, v2;

  eqn(&q, &w, &e);

  scanf("%d%d", &h, &j);

  v1 = val(q, w, e, h);
  v2 = val(q, w, e, j);

  printf("values %f %f\n", v1, v2);

  return 0;
}

int eqn(float * pq, float * pw, float * pe)
{
  scanf("%f %f %f", pq, pw, pe);

  printf("Entered equation: %.2fx^2 + %.2fx + %.2f\n", *pq, *pw, *pe);
} 

float val(float q, float w, float e, int x)
{
  float value = q*x*x + w*x + e;
  return value;
}
```

To define the scope of your variables even tighter change `main()` to look like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  float q, w, e;
  eqn(&q, &w, &e);

  {
    int h, j;
    scanf("%d%d", &h, &j);

    {
      float v1 = val(q, w, e, h);
      float v2 = val(q, w, e, j);

      printf("values %f %f\n", v1, v2);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```